# Parameter pack cannot be expanded

Tags: c++, c++20, variadic-templates

```
template<integral auto n1, decltype(n1) n2, class callable_t, class... args_t> requires (n1 <= n2)
constexpr void const_for(callable_t&& callable, args_t&&... args)
{
    callable<n1>(forward<args_t>(args)...);

    if constexpr (n1 < n2) { callable<n1 + 1>(forward<args_t>(args)...); }
}
```

I can't understand what is the problem here. But in visual studio 2022, it gives the following errors (line 4 and 6):

> Error C2760   syntax error: '...' was unexpected here; expected ')'
>
> Error C2760   syntax error: ')' was unexpected here; expected ';'
>
> Error C3878   syntax error: unexpected token ')' following
> 'expression_statement'

etc.

Comment: Don't know what this does, but I have seen something like `callable.template operator()<n1>(forward<args_t>(args)...);` in a post and the same for the other call as well. Compiles fine for me.

Comment: Just found this: [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lemme reduce to just one argument to make this clearer:

```cpp
callable<n1>(arg);
```

What this means, given an *object* (i.e., not a function template, not a variable template, but an actual object) is:

```cpp
(callable < n1) > (arg)
```

That is, the `<` is parsed as the less-than operator, not as an introducer for template arguments. This is one of the issues with using `<>`s for both contexts (and why the D language, for instance, uses `!` - which is one of those syntactic choices that seems incredibly jarring when you first see it but is definitely a good idea).

In some contexts, you can use the `template` keyword to disambiguate that no, you do actually mean to introduce template arguments. You'd see something like:

```cpp
using A = typename B::template C<D>;
```

But here, that's not an option - because, again, `callable` is an object, and objects can't take template arguments.

The solutions here are:

- either explicitly invoke the call operator, which would be `callable.operator()<n1>(arg)`
- pass the template parameter as an argument, that is: `callable(integral_constant<decltype(n1), n1>(), arg)`

The latter has a lot going for it and is a pretty nice pattern, so I would recommend doing that. It becomes nicer with an alias:

```cpp
template <auto V>
using constant = std::integral_constant<decltype(V), V>;
```

Because then `callable(constant<n1>(), arg)`.

Comment: Would `std::invoke()` also be one of the solutions?

Comment: @TobySpeight No, why would you think so?

Comment: I haven't thought it through, but it's the obvious way to invoke `operator()`: why won't `std::invoke(&callable_t::operator<n1>(), callable, arg);` be a sensible alternative?  TBH, I'm still scrabbling to imagine the use-case for template `operator()` (as opposed to operator in a template class).

Comment: @TobySpeight That's... strictly worse than I wrote. For one thing, it's much longer. For another, the call operator is likely itself a template on multiple types, so you'd have to spell all of those out in order to form the pointer-to-member properly - which is easy to get wrong.

Comment: @TobySpeight The use-case for a call operator template is really the same as the use-case for any template anytime you want to explicitly provide a template argument. It's just that the function you're calling happens to be named `()`

Comment: I see., so the problem is not in the pack expansion, it is that a generic functor object cannot be called directly as I have written.